# Как перенести слово "в сторону"?

Tags: орфография

"В сторону" - как перенести?

Comment: Для начала научиться грамотно писать. Вы что-нибудь слышали о знаках препинания и о большой букве в начале предложения?

Answer (score 1):

Слово *сторону* переносим по слогам: сто-ро-ну. А предлог можно спокойно отделять от следующего за ним существительного, поскольку это разные слова.